# What is the probability that it will last another 2 hours?

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution

Suppose that the time a machine can operate before breaking down is exponentially distributed with a mean of 10 hours. If the machine has already been operating for 2 hours, what is the probability that it will last another 2 hours?

my try is ==>
P(2< x <4) = P(X<4) - P(X<2)

my output is 0.1484 which is incorrect , any help as I am fresh learner?

Comment: Does conditional probability have anything to do with this question?

Comment: What do you know about the exponential distribution? Forget formulas and expressions, what is, in your opinion, the _defining feature_ of the exponential distribution?

Comment: @Arthur
I will be grateful if you explain it in smooth way